# search for a file with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am developing an simple searching tool for my purpose.
My intention is to search all files or specific file under the specified folder.
I thought  to do with multiple threads.
Each thread will start searching for a file and put that file into a list if that file 
does not contain in the list.
So each thread will not scan for the same file .

I am not sure this is the right approach or not.
And when I run the program, I could see the same result when I use one thread,two
and even more than two.

Then I used Executor service, still I am getting the same executing time.I could not 
find the difference. My questions are below.

1.Am I using right logic for searching file with multiple threads?

2.can I get the difference when executing with one thread,two threads,etc?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileReaderRunnable implements Runnable {

    private List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    private File mfile;

    public boolean finished;
    public FileReaderRunnable(File file) {
        this.mfile = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //System.out.println("Thread current:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        //while(!finished){
            getfiles(mfile);
            //finished = false;
        //}

    }

    public void setFlag(boolean value) {
        finished = value;
    }

    public void getfiles(File file) {
        System.out.println("EXecuting...: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+file.getAbsolutePath());
        File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file2 : listFiles) {
                if(!fileList.contains(file2.getAbsoluteFile())){
                    fileList.add(file2.getAbsoluteFile());  
                }               
                getfiles(file2);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<File> getFiles(){
        return fileList ;
    }

}

public class FileReaderThreadMain { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
        File file = new File("C:\\Temp");
        FileReaderRunnable r = new FileReaderRunnable(file);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        executor.execute(r);    
        executor.shutdown();
        // Wait until all threads are finish
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) { 
        }       
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();       
        System.out.println("\nFinished all threads");   
        System.out.println("main thread exited");       
        List<File> files = r.getFiles();
        System.out.println("Total Files size: "+files.size());      
        long duration = (endTime - startTime);
        System.out.println("Duration: "+duration/1000000 );     
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems that there is only one thread, isn't?

Comment: you have only one instance of `FileReaderRunnable` so there is only one worker. Try to create few instances of it to provide to `executor `

Comment: Is there some specific reason you are using thread for this?

Comment: Unless you are searching in multiple physical filesystems, you will probably not find any advantage making your code parallel, because **all requests will go to the same filesystem, which will process them one by one**.

Comment: If you are searching a single hard disk drive, multiple threads is liable to slow down the process considerably. One thread has the hard drive seek to a location and read, then the next thread has the hard drive seek to a different location and read, etc. All the seeking is not necessary, and a single-threaded set of calls to one driver can have the seeks and reads optimized to some extent. Just putting things in multiple threads not only doesn't make things faster, sometimes it makes them slower.

Comment: My intention was to minimize the time. suppose if I have to scan the entire C drive, then with one thread it might long time. That was the reason I decided to go with multiple threads. some thread will do the portion of disk,and other thread will do the other portion of disk ,etc like wise

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
public class Test {

    private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 3;
    private static int taskDoneCount=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        List<String> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        File dir = new File("C:\\Temp");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        int length = files.length;
        int onePart = length / THREAD_COUNT;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
            int startIndex = i * onePart; // the start index of the file list
            int endIndex = onePart * (i + 1);// the end index of the file list
            if (i == THREAD_COUNT-1) {
                endIndex = files.length;
            }
            System.out.println("Thread#"+(i+1)+" start index:"+startIndex+", end index:"+(endIndex-1));
            executor.execute(new SearchFileThread(startIndex, endIndex, files, fileList -> {
                synchronized (Test.class) {
                    taskDoneCount++;
                    allFiles.addAll(fileList);
                    if (taskDoneCount == THREAD_COUNT) {// check if all tasks finished
                        executor.shutdown(); // shutdown the thread pool
                        System.out.println("allFiles = " + allFiles);
                        System.out.println("allFiles.size() = " + allFiles.size());
                        System.out.println("Time used: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)+"ms");
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    static private class SearchFileThread implements Runnable {
        private int startIndex;
        private int endIndex;
        private File[] listFiles;
        private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        private TaskFinishListener listener;

        public SearchFileThread(int startIndex, int endIndex, File[] listFiles, TaskFinishListener listener) {
            this.startIndex = startIndex;
            this.endIndex = endIndex;
            this.listFiles = listFiles;
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
                fileList.add(listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
            listener.onFinish(fileList);
        }
    }

    private interface TaskFinishListener {
        void onFinish(List<String> fileList);
    }
}
```